# Reg calculating system idle time

Tags: java, events, swing

Please help me on the below problem

How to find out the System idle time, means to calcuclate the time the user keeps the system idle (ie without moving the mouse and without touching the keyboard) and between which time the system is idle .Also i should require an excel or mail to be send to the user with the summation of all the idle times for that day & for that particular system.

Regards,
Chandu.

Comment: I think you should use JNI/JNA to do this... For windows you should call `GetLastInputInfo` (not sure about *X). And I don't think `swing` has anything to do with this.

Comment: This might do something similar https://jdic.dev.java.net/incubator/systeminfo/index.html

Answer (score 6):

You can find out where the user's mouse is using [PointerInfo](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/PointerInfo.html):

```
MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation()
```

Keep polling the pointer location use this method and if you find that the location has changed since the last time you checked, reset the idle time back to 0. Here is some test code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    long idleTime = 0 ;
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Point currLocation = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
    while(true){
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        Point newLocation = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
        if(newLocation.equals(currLocation)){
            //not moved
            idleTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        }
        else{
            System.out.printf("Idle time was: %s ms", idleTime);
            idleTime=0;
            start =  System.currentTimeMillis();
            break;
        }
        currLocation = newLocation;

    }
}
```

Also take a look at [this blog post](http://ochafik.free.fr/blog/?p=98), which detects idle time using JNA.